# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' while posting data

Tags: python, list, lxml

I want to post some parameters in order to login to my page:

```
session=requests.Session()
cont=session.get('http://mywebsite.com/').content
tree=html.fromstring(cont)
token=tree.xpath[...]
post_data={'A':'B', token:'1'}
```

In last line it give me the error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Evidently `token` is a list, so can't be used as a dictionary key. What exactly is confusing you?

Comment: How can I change `post_data` format in order to make fine?

Comment: Well the simplest would be using `tuple(token)`, but were you *expecting to get a list?*

Comment: We don't know, from the information you give, what your page requires for login.

Comment: There is nothing specific about the `requests` module here. It is your use of `lxml` that is the cause.

Comment: @MortezaLSC that's exactly why I *haven't* answered - why not just `token[0]`?! Are there other elements in `token`, and are you happy to just ignore them? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lxml` `tree.xpath()` method returned a list object. You cannot use a list object as a dictionary key.

If you meant to retrieve the *first* (perhaps *only*) result of the XPath query, then do so explicitly:

```
post_data={'A': 'B', token[0]: '1'}
```

If you needed to use *all* results of the query (anywhere between 0 and however much your memory can hold), convert the list to a tuple:

```
post_data={'A': 'B', tuple(token): '1'}
```

Comment: @MortezaLSC: why would converting the list object to a tuple be more correct? Extracting the element at index 0 is still going to result in the *exact same object*.

Comment: :)  Yes. I am going to accept it :)   +1   token[0] is correct as well